# How to insert timestamp in nano editor?

Tags: nano

I need a time-stamp that is inserted with a hot key, like F5 in old notepad. Format should be:

```
hh:mm dd.mm.yyyy.
```

p.s. Dot in the end of the year is grammatically correct in Serbian language, so it is not a mistake.

Comment: I think it is not possible without patching the source code. But you can get this stamp in terminal by `date +%H:%M\ %d.%m.%Y.`. You can set an alias for this command to enter it fast.

Answer (score 2):

1. Install the package `xdotool` via, we need the command `xdotool`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xdotool
   ```
2. Create a small script

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   sleep 0.1
   xdotool type $(date +"%H:%M")' '$(date +"%d.%m.%Y.")
   ```

   - If the output does not looks something like

     ```
     17:31 15.08.2015.
     ```

     use

     ```
     #!/bin/bash
     sleep 0.1
     xdotool type $(date +"%H")':'$(date +"%M")' '$(date +"%d")'.'$(date +"%m")'.'$(date +"%Y")'.'
     ```
   - **If the time is not fully inserted after pressing the shortcut, increment the parameter for `sleep`, eg `0.5`, in the script**
3. Make it executable

   ```
   chmod +x your_script
   ```
4. Assign a keyboard shortcut for the script, eg <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> *or some other shortcut that is not used.*

   [image]

Comment: Did you test it in nano? It has another binding for F5. But it can be undone in `.nanorc`

Comment: @Pilot6 No :) only in gedit and in a terminal … But Super+F5 should work.

Comment: Super+F5 will open an app from launcher. F5 works but shows `18^01 15.08.2015.`

Comment: @Pilot6 `18^01`? why the `^`? o_O

Comment: @Pilot6 Can you test it with `xdotool type $(date +"%H")':'$(date +"%M")' '$(date +"%d")'.'$(date +"%m")'.'$(date +"%Y.")` please?

Comment: I already tried it.  Same thing.

Comment: Could you please elaborate how to bind the keyboard shortcut?

Comment: @Inspired_Blue point 4 in my answer

Comment: I am unable to follow. I did the following: 1. Open keyboard>Shortcuts>Custom Shortcuts. 2. Click on the + button and window popped up. 3. In name I typed 'InsertTime' and in command './xdotool.sh' and clicked apply. 4. The row appeared with disabled next to it. I clicked on disabled and pressed 'Super+F5'. The changes appeared. 5. I go back to the terminal and pressed Super+F5. Nothing happened. Why? 6. But if I type xdotool.sh it prints the time and date as I want.

Comment: @Inspired_Blue Is the script execuable? Try increment the parameter for `sleep ` and use the full path of the script in your shortcut

Answer (score 0):

This answer was tested with Nano 6.4.

As far as I can tell, Nano doesn't ship with a keyboard shortcut that inserts a timestamp of the current time and date. However, Nano does offer features that allow you to configure some stuff so you can do this:

1. You can execute external programs, and print the output into Nano.
2. You can make custom keyboard shortcuts, including ones that can execute external commands, using macro-like actions along with it. You do not actually need to use Nano's standard macro feature, however.

So, you can use a third-party command-line timestamp program, and make a keyboard shortcut that uses it.

Here is how to do this:

Open your Nanorc file with Nano (not another text editor, because you'll need to make use of Nano's verbatim input feature); you can do `nano ~/.nanorc` to open the Nanorc file.

Type the following on its own line (which makes use of the idea that Pilot06 mentioned in the comments):

```
bind F5 "date +%I:%M\ %d.%m.%Y." main
```

Or if you want 24-hour time do this instead:

```
bind F5 "date +%H:%M\ %d.%m.%Y." main
```

Now, go between the `"d` and press Alt+v; then press Ctrl+t.

Now, go between the `."` and press Alt+v and then press enter.

Then press Alt+v and press backspace, once.

Your line should look something like this (but it might look a little different, and don't copy/paste this, because it probably won't count the special characters as verbatim input):

```
bind F5 "^Tdate +%I:%M\ %d.%m.%Y.^M^?" main
```

Save and close Nano. You're done. It won't work in instances of Nano that are already open (you'll have to close those and restart them).

Now, whenever you press F5, it'll insert a timestamp according as you wanted.

To see directives for the command-line program called `date`, type `man date`, `date --help`, or `info date` (press q to get out of the manpage or the info page). Directives are the things like %H.

Here's an example of a fancy timestamp:

`date +%-d\ %B\ %-Y\ \(%A\)—%-I:%M:%S\ %p`